# GHC 7.4 update breaks haskell98?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I updated ghc today and my small program stopped working:

https://github.com/BrisFunctional/misere-oxo/blob/master/OXO/misere.hs

GHC is now version 7.4.1-2 and from what I managed to understand it now defaults
to  haskell2010 standard, instead of haskell98. (as I can see from the output of ghc-pkg list):

```
haskell2010-1.1.0.1
(haskell98-2.0.0.1)
```

So I changed my "import List" to "import Data.List" which I thought was the only problem but now I get the following:

```
 misere.hs:1:1: Not in scope: `System.Environment.withArgs'
```

where does that come from since I never even import System.Environment?
Any hint?
Thanks

EDIT:
I updated the version on github to reflect this error. and actually using Data.List ghc compiles the file perfectly, so it's runhaskell that generates this problem..

Comment: Did you try compiling with `ghc -XHaskell98`?

Comment: that option doesn't exist on my ghc, I was actually looking for something similar..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need not only change `List` to `Data.List`, but also `Random` to `System.Random` and import `getArgs` from `System.Environment` (but at the moment, the code uses neither `getArgs` nor anything from `System.Random`, so for the time being, you can also remove those imports).

The old non-hierarchical modules are only accessible from the `haskell98` package, which is no longer compatible with `base`. That means that using the `haskell98` modules also requires explicitly hiding `base` on the command line, or not listing `base` in the dependencies field of the `.cabal` file.

I'm a bit surprised by the error message, I would expect it to say

```
Could not find module `System'
It is a  member of the hidden package `haskell98-2.0.0.1'.
```

but that difference may be a quirk of `runhaskell`.

Comment: Well sorry the version that was on the link is not the same I was actually working on, I pushed the current version on github and that gets me the error displayed before.

Comment: That's odd. I get no errors running the new version either with runhaskell or directly from the shell, and there's no reason for that error in the file. What does `runhaskell --version` report? Not that I expect anything but `runghc 7.4.1`, but I'd like to make sure.

Comment: Yes I get exactly that version, I just tried on another machine with the previous version of GHC, and everything works fine... Maybe I'll just try to reinstall all the haskell-related packages on my Archlinux and see if that works.

Comment: Seems a drastic measure, but on the other hand, that weird error on only(?) that one machine speaks for a botched installation.

Comment: Yes, I updated GHC also on this machine and it still runs perfectly also with runhaskell. So the problem is probably related to conflicts with the packages previously installed via cabal, a cleanup should fix the issues..

Answer (score 6):

If your program is pure Haskell98 you can use the following GHC invokation:

```
ghc -package haskell98 -hide-package base
```

In the long term, though, it would be better if you upgraded at least to hierarchical module names.  Use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to find out the name of the module.  E.g., `http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=withArgs` lists `System.Environment` as the exporting module.

Answer (score 2):

First, i think you do use System.Environment.withArgs because of getArgs, which uses withArgs. [Hackage.Haskell page for System.Environment](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Environment.html)

Try importing `withArgs` as well, and maybe whole `System.Environment`.

Secondly, it might be the case that `List` used to have more than `Data.List` now has. You might want to try to include the whole `Prelude` instead of just `Data.List`.

And to answer the question in the header, every update of GHC extends Haskell98. And some language pragma's even brake some Haskell98 specifics. But mostly changes in libraries cause problems, and not GHC updates themselves.

Hopefully i have given you enough to solve the problems.

Comment: As I wrote above these things are not a problem anymore, and the program compiles fine, that error comes from runhaskell..